# F# Deedle GetSlice() error "expects to have type DateTime option"

Tags: f#, deedle, fslab

I am getting an error when trying to use the GetSlice() method.

```
cl.Rows.GetSlice( DateTime(2014,12,28,20,0,0), DateTime(2014,12,28,23,0,0))
```

The error is: This expression  was expected to have type DateTime option but here has type DateTime.  This error is given for both parameters ( *DateTime(2014,12,28,20,0,0)*, *DateTime(2014,12,28,23,0,0)* ) in the above code

Could some one explain the differnce between type of 'DateTime option' a type of 'DateTime'.  What would be the correct correct syntax to use for the above code?

FsLab version(0.3.17)

Comment: See: [Options (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) and [The Option type](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `GetSlice` expects both parameter of type `DateTime option` (as the compiler helpfully tells you), but you're providing just `DateTime`.

To create a value of type `'t option`, use constructor `Some`:

```
cl.Rows.GetSlice( Some (DateTime(2014,12,28,20,0,0)), Some (DateTime(2014,12,28,23,0,0)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) is a type which either encapsulates a value of a certain type or it indicates that there's no value. In F#, there are two ways to write its type: `Option<'t>` or `'t option`.

The main motivation behind using option is to produce type-save and bug-free code - it makes using `null`s and some `Exception`s (e.g. `KeyNotFoundExcpetion`s) obsolete.

Comment: I am very new to F# and had come across  the Type Option.  But I was unable to make the connection when I saw 'DateTime option'.  The biggest problem I am having with deedle is understanding  the syntax of what the compiler tells me it is expecting.  Until I am able to comprehend the syntax I am left to guessing  as to what to enter.

Comment: If you find yourself unable to comprehend the syntax, that may indicate that some initial learning of concepts is in order. I recommend starting with the excellent resource http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com, and specifically for your case, [this section on expressions and syntax](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/expressions-and-syntax.html).

Comment: @rhscJohn - I thought that you were confused because you didn't understand what "'t option" means (it might be something new for somebody from C# or Java background) and that you are familiar with basics of F#'s typesystem and documentation. 
I agree with Fyodor - fsharpforfunandprofit.com is a great learning resource and I also recommend it.